# HTML double links

Tags: html

I have 2 sets of links on my html page, one for the top and bottom of the page, and one for different pages. But I want to change the second one. After I put this code

```
a:link {
color: green;
background-color: transparent;
text-decoration: none;
        }
       a:visited {
color: pink;
background-color: transparent;
text-decoration: none;
       }
         a:hover {
color: red;
background-color: transparent;
text-decoration: underline;
          }
      a:active {
color: yellow;
background-color: transparent;
text-decoration: underline;
  }`
```

everything on my page becomes those colors. What can I do to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `class` attribute of links contaner to define special style for links inside it. For example:

```css
/* General link style */
a {
  color: #0000FF;
}

/* Style for a link inside .special container */
.special a {
  color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">Link A</a>
</div>
<div class="special">
  <a href="#">Link B</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#">Link C</a>
</div>
```